# Page scrolls upwards when loading new content with infinite scroll + lazy load

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using Paul Irish's infinite scroll plugin as well as using lazy load on my tumblr blog.

Basically, when you scroll to the bottom of the page, the new content will be loaded in.

The problem I'm having is that, when the new content gets loaded in, the page keeps scrolling upwards (viewport).

Is there something I'm missing? I just want the viewport to stay fixed on the current position and to load everything underneath the so called 'fold' when the infinite scroll function gets called.

Is this because if you scroll to the bottom too quickly, then images above the 'fold' still get loaded in, forcing the page to appear to scroll "up". If so, maybe infinite scroll isn't appropriate for my blog?

You can check it out here: http://blog.rainbird.me/

Cheers Will.

Comment: hey. yes that's the exact reason for it, images are loading and the position stays in the same but the content is expanding, drop the lazyload if you want to fix it but you will lose the whole 'load if needed' functionality, the quick fix (but a painful one from the maintanance point of view) is to force the width and height for all images but you wuold need to do it manually with inline styles or with server-side script as there's no point of getting the original argument - you would need to load this image to get the size, sorry it's actually a working solution

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to make sure you specify the correct **width** and **height** on all the images on your page.

This will help you will the attractiveness of the page anyway while it is loading. Otherwise, text and elements jump all around as the page continues to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

Something else you could try if it's not possible to set image heights:

1. Capture scroll position before loading image
2. Load image
3. If image is "above" scroll position... get the calculated height of the image and add it to scroll position to push user down further.